# Why is this shortcode displayed twice on the page?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to add a rating shortcode on the page, for example [rating rating="3"], but the problem is that it displays twice.

```
function rating_function($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'rating' => 5, 
    'type' => 'rating', 
    'number' => 0 
  ), $atts));
return wp_star_rating(array('rating' => $rating, 'type' => $type, 'number' => $number));
}
add_shortcode('rating', 'rating_function');
```

Comment: Could you please add some more details to your question? Remember, this is a very large community with many different programming languages, so include the information that you are trying to do it on wordpress on your question body.

Comment: So I gave your code a try and indeed it does output the rating twice. I had a look at the documentation and figured out why that's happening. Please check my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing the rating twice is because by default the [wp_star_rating()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_star_rating/) function echoes the generated rating HTML markup. From the documentation:

> $args (array) (Optional) Array of star ratings arguments.
>
> - 'rating' (int|float) The rating to display, expressed in either a 0.5 rating increment, or percentage. Default 0.
> - 'type' (string) Format that the $rating is in. Valid values are 'rating' (default), or, 'percent'. Default 'rating'.
> - 'number' (int) The number of ratings that makes up this rating. Default 0.
> - 'echo' (bool) **Whether to echo the generated markup. False to return the markup instead of echoing it. Default true**.
>
> Default value: array()

(Emphasis mine.)

When using this function within a shortcode you must make sure that the function *returns* the HTML markup, not *echo* it:

```
function rating_function($atts) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/template.php');

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'rating' => 5, 
        'type' => 'rating', 
        'number' => 0 
    ), $atts));

    return wp_star_rating(array(
        'rating' => $rating,
        'type' => $type,
        'number' => $number,
        'echo' => false
    ));
}
add_shortcode('rating', 'rating_function');
```